# Dynamic handling event in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to abstract the handling event in react, so instead of

```
export const Button = ({handlerFunction, text}) => {

return(
    <button onClick = {()=>handlerFunction()} >{text}</button>
)}
```

it is something like

```
export const Button = ({handlingEvent, handlerFunction, text}) => {

return(
    <button `{handlingEvent}` = {()=>handlerFunction()} >{text}</button>
)}
```

which of course doesn't work. Some ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: how about passing event from parent => https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-austin-ues104?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Button = ({
  handlingEvent,
  handlerFunction,
  text
}) => {

  return (
    <button {...{ [handlingEvent]: () => handlerFunction()}}>
      {text}
    </button>
  )
}
```